# insert text using grep

Tags: macos, shell

I have bunch of java files in a directory and want to insert package declaration in them if they already don't have them. Can I accomplish it with grep? and if yes please tell me how?

thanks.

Comment: No. You need one of the other tools. sed/awk etc.

Comment: Grep can only help you identify the files that lack a package declaration (see the `-l` switch, which will list only the filenames that match your regular expression). You could perhaps use sed to modify the files, using something like `for f in $(grep -l "expression" *); do sed -i "commands to modify $f go here"; done`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. `grep` is officially described as `print lines matching a pattern`.

It is a *filter*, it does not output anything that wasn't there already (but it may output less). In particular, it will not be able to output a *missing* package declaration. You can however use it to test whether a file does have a package declaration:

```
 <insert your favorite "for each java file" statement>
   if egrep -q "^package " $file; then
     <insert command to insert package declaration> $file
   fi
 <end loop>
```

You probably are looking for `awk`, although `perl` is also a popular choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

foreach a ( `ls *.java` )

    cat ${a} | awk 'BEGIN {P=0} /package/ {P=1} /import/ {if (P == 0) {P=1;print "package X;"}} {print}' > t1
    mv t1 ${a}

end
```

It looks for the word `package` and `import`.
If it sees `import` before `package` then it print "package X".